# perl using coderef as parameter to subroutine

Tags: perl, callback, perl-data-structures

I have the following subroutines:

```
sub my_sub {
    my $coderef = shift;    
    $coderef->();
}


sub coderef {
    my $a = shift;
    my $b = shift;

    print $a+$b;
}
```

and want to call `my_sub(\coderef($a,$b))` in this manner i.e I want to provide the arguments of the code ref with it and run it on the my_sub function. Is it possible to do something like this in perl?

Comment: Besides being non-descriptive names, `$a` and `$b` are [special package variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$a) used with `sort`, so using them for other reasons is not a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If those subs are to be taken at face value, `my_sub` isn't doing anything.

There are two things going on here:

1. Define the coderef

   ```
   my $adder = sub { my ( $first, $second ) = @_; $first + $second };

   # Adds first two arguments
   ```
2. Execute it with the necessary parameters

   ```
   print $adder->(2,3);  # '5'
   ```

---

Assuming `my_sub` is some kind of a functor that is passed the coderef as its first argument:

```
sub functor {
    my $coderef = shift;  # Pull of first argument
    $coderef->( @_ );     # Rest of @_ are coderef arguments
                          # Or simply : sub functor { +shift->( @_ ) }
}

# Usage:

print functor ( $adder, 2, 3 );  # '5'
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to wrap the call to your `coderef` subroutine in another anonymous subroutine, like so:

```
my_sub(sub { coderef(2, 3); }); # replace 2, 3 with whatever arguments
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
use warnings;
use strict;

&my_sub( \&coderef );

sub my_sub {
    my $coderef = shift;
    $coderef->(2, 3);
}

sub coderef {
    my $a= shift;
    my $b = shift;

    print $a+$b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous subroutine.

```
my $coderef = sub {
    my ($aa, $bb) = @_;
    print $aa + $bb;
};

sub my_sub {
    my ($c_ref, @params) = @_;
    $c_ref->(@params);
}

my_sub($coderef, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea. Perhaps a closure solves your problem? If you write `coderef` as a factory then you can code like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my_sub(coderef(2,3));

sub my_sub {
  my $coderef = shift;    
  $coderef->();
}

sub coderef {
    my $a = shift;
    my $b = shift;

    return sub { print $a + $b };
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
5
```